# ElasticSearch connector - Inverse IRIs in property chains

Tags: graphdb

I see in the 9.7 release notes that line :

> GDB-5477 Add support for inverse IRIs in the connectors property chains

Is this functionality usable ? I can't find the documentation in [ES Connectors pages](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/elasticsearch-graphdb-connector.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality is useful if you want to filter out specific property chains. For examle:

```
{
   "fieldName":"operatesEquipment_variantOfFamily_label",
   "propertyChain":[
      "^http://example.com/nested/other/operatedBy",
      "^http://example.com/nested/other/owns",
      "http://example.com/nested/core/label"
   ],
   "indexed":true,
   "stored":true,
   "analyzed":true,
   "multivalued":true,
   "fielddata":false
}
```

If you insert data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/> .

:family2 <http://example.com/nested/core/label> "test" ;
         <http://example.com/nested/other/owns> :equipement1 .
```

The expected result won't have anything related to operatedBy or owns:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "label": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    "operatesEquipment_variantOfFamily_label": {
      "store": true,
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```